# Openpyxl bar chart with two different Reference

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a problem with building complex barchart in openpyxl v3.1.1. All guides have simple example:

```
chart1 = BarChart()
data = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_row=7, max_col=3)  # Y data
cats = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=7) # X data
chart1.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
# or series_2 = Series(data_dec, title=f"Title") when Title not the first row
# chart1.append(series_2)
chart1.set_categories(cats)
ws.add_chart(chart1, "A10")  # draw chart
```

But Reference contains only one block of "rows", but I need more then one. In MS Excel I can do it with press Ctrl and choose another block of "rows".

Is it possible to do same in openpyxl?

Tiny example illustrating my problem I got table

| Data-1 | Data-2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2010-Jan-1 | 0.1 |
| 2010-Jan-2 | 0.2 |
| 2010-Jan-1 | 0.3 |
| 2010-Feb-1 | 0.4 |
| 2010-Feb-2 | 0.5 |
| 2010-Feb-3 | 0.6 |
| 2011-Jan-1 | 0.7 |
| 2011-Jan-2 | 0.8 |
| 2011-Jan-3 | 0.9 |

I need to build one chart of January (2010-Jan-1, 2010-Jan-2, 2010-Jan-3, 2011-Jan-1, 2011-Jan-2, 2011-Jan-3) and in MS Excel that cells I can pick with Ctrl button and got formula like this: =test_1!$A$2:$A$4;test_1!$A$8:$A$10

But in openpyxl can't find anything to unite two References.

Comment: It may be possible to do in Openpyxl, but not straight forward. A few people have asked before, with no solutions proposed. Openpyxl Reference expects contiguous data selection so would probably require some hacking. Other modules like Xlwings and Xlsxwriter are able to accept the non contiguous range values so can create the chart. However I wonder how usable the chart would be given there'd be large gap between the two date ranges. Of course your working data may be for illustration only and not for real world use.

Comment: I got you, thanks. Better cope data to another list to make it contiguous. About usage and usability... chart is needed to show change of data in season (winter, spring etc.) for several years.

Answer (score 1):

Examples of creating the chart using XLSXWriter and XlWings.

**XLSXWRITER**
With xlsxwriter you can just enter the non contiguous range as `=test_1!$A$2:$A$4;test_1!$A$8:$A$10` although this does trigger a warning message as xlsxwriter cannot extract the sheet name from this range correctly. It indicates the sheet name (as extracted) does not exist in the workbook's list of sheets but otherwise doesn't appear to affect the creation of the workbook and chart.

```
sheet_name = 'test_1'
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("xlsxwriter_chart.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(sheet_name)

### Formatting for data
bold = workbook.add_format({"bold": 1})
# date_format = workbook.add_format({"num_format": "d/mm/yyyy"})
date_format = workbook.add_format({"num_format": "yyyy-mmm-d"})
value_format = workbook.add_format({"num_format": "0.0"})

# Worksheet data that the charts will use
headings = ['Data-1', 'Data-2']
data_list = [
    [40179, 0.1],
    [40180, 0.2],
    [40181, 0.3],
    [40210, 0.4],
    [40211, 0.5],
    [40212, 0.6],
    [40544, 0.7],
    [40545, 0.8],
    [40546, 0.9],
]

### Add data to Sheet with some formatting
worksheet.write_row("A1", headings, bold)
for row, data in enumerate(data_list, 2):
    worksheet.write(f"A{row}", data[0], date_format)
    worksheet.write(f"B{row}", data[1], value_format)

### Create the Bar chart.
chart = workbook.add_chart({"type": "bar"})

### Adjust chart objects to display values better
chart.set_x_axis({
    'major_gridlines': {
        'visible': False,
    },
})
chart.set_y_axis({
    "date_axis": True,
    "min": date(2009, 12, 1),
    "max": date(2011, 2, 1),
})

# Configure the series ranges.
chart.add_series(
    {
        "categories": f"={sheet_name}!$A$2:$A$4,{sheet_name}!$A$8:$A$10",
        "values": f"={sheet_name}!$B$2:$B$4,{sheet_name}!$B$8:$B$10",
        "gridline": False
    }
)

### Insert the chart into the worksheet (with an offset).
worksheet.insert_chart("D2", chart, {"x_offset": 25, "y_offset": 10})

### Widen column A for date values
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 10)

### Save workbook
workbook.close(
```

**XLWINGS**
Similarly you can just enter the non contiguous range either with 'set_source_data' or 'FullSeriesCollection' though FullSeriesCollection needs the sheet name included in the range.

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings import constants

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book()
    ws = wb.sheets[0]
    ws.name = 'test_1'

    # Add the worksheet data to be plotted.
    data = [10, 40, 50, 20, 10, 50]
    data_list = [
        ['Data-1', 'Data-2'],
        [40179, 0.1],
        [40180, 0.2],
        [40181, 0.3],
        [40210, 0.4],
        [40211, 0.5],
        [40212, 0.6],
        [40544, 0.7],
        [40545, 0.8],
        [40546, 0.9],
    ]
    ### Format the cells with data
    ws.range('A1').value = data_list
    ws.range('A1:B1').font.bold = True
    ws.range('A2:A10').number_format = "yyyy-mmm-d"

    ### Create new chart object Chart.
    chart = ws.charts.add(left=200, top=10, width=520, height=380)

    ### Add Chart and set type
    chart.api[1].SeriesCollection().NewSeries()
    chart.api[1].FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = constants.ChartType.xlBarClustered

    ### Select non-contiguous range for X axis
    chart.set_source_data(ws.range('B2:B4, B8:B10'))
    ### Select non-contiguous range for Y axis
    chart.api[1].FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = f"={ws.name}!A2:A4,{ws.name}!A8:A10"

    ### Set date range scale
    chart.api[1].Axes(constants.AxisType.xlCategory).MinimumScale = 40148
    chart.api[1].Axes(constants.AxisType.xlCategory).MaximumScale = 40575
    chart.api[1].Axes(2).MajorGridlines.Delete()

    wb.save('xlwings_chart.xlsx')
    wb.close()
```

As mentioned the chart may not be very useful though with the values squashed at top and bottom
[image]

Comment: You can avoid the XlsxWriter warning by putting the non-contiguous ranges in parentheses `=(...)`. That is the syntax Excel uses when storing those ranges. XlsxWriter recognises that and doesn't issue a parse warning. For example `"categories": f"=({sheet_name}!$A$2:$A$4,{sheet_name}!$A$8:$A$10)",`.

Comment: Thanks for example, but I have a little problem with it, my example is only a part of bigger program, that open xlsx file, modify it and save. As far as I remember, xlsxwriter use only for write xlsx files. In my case it's better to copy data to another list in book with format that I need. Thanks anyway.